# Como retornar imagem sem estar salva no banco de dados?

Tags: processamento-de-imagens

Eu irei armazenar as imagens na pasta *img* dentro do meu site. Queria saber se existe alguma forma para buscar uma determinada imagem usando o formulário de busca, para que, quando fosse feita a busca, ela fosse exibida em um determinado local do site -- ou para isso eu teria que salvar todas as imagens no banco de dados?

Comment: uma estrategia seria vc armazenar no banco uma tabela contendo o caminho das imagens e alguns tipos de descricao, como se fosse uma nuvem de tags. Assim ao pesquisar, o usuário receberia as informacoes do banco mas o load das imagens e seus arquivos físicos estariam fora do banco.

Comment: E como faria esse load, tu poderia me fornecer um exemplo em codigo???

Comment: Está usando qual linguagem de programação para o back-end de seu site? Seria PHP mesmo? Outra duvida, a busca do form deve buscar pelo nome do arquivo?

Comment: estou usando PHP, e a busca vai ser pelo nome da imagem sim!!